# Rails 4 not showing imgaes in Production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I read through every link on Stack Overflow and Google. I have spent many hours trying stuff. But could not figure this issue out.

I have following folder structure in my app assets

```
app
  ->images
   ->application (folder)
    image1..
    image2..
   ->icons (folder)
     image3..
     image4..
```

I have application.css file in my stylesheets folder like below:

```
 app
  ->stylesheets (folder)
     application.css
    ->application (folder)
       app.css
```

The application.css has following entry:

```
*= require_tree ./application
```

Thus it is loading my app.css file which has all the css for my app. In my app.css I am using :

```
{background: url('icons/user-business-gray.png') no-repeat 2px center transparent;}
```

My  config/environments/production.rb has :

```
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  #config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
```

My config/initializers/assets.rb has :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join( "app/assets/images/application")
```

I did :

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

I can see all my images hashed in public/assets, public/assets/application and public/assets/icons properly.

It all works fine in development mode. But I cannot see any images referenced in in app.css file in production mode.

If I add an image to .erb directly using `<%= image_tag('icons/user-business-gray.png') %>` I can see the image correctly. But I cannot see any images referenced from app.css as referenced above.

I even changed the name of app.css to app.css.scss and referenced the image like :

```
{background: url(assets-path('icons/user-business-gray.png')) no-repeat 2px center transparent;}
```

but still the same issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the filename to `app.css.scss` and using the `assert-url` helper:

```
{background: asset-url('icons/user-business-gray.png') no-repeat 2px center transparent;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has fixed the issue:

```
{background: image-url('icons/user-business-gray.png') no-repeat 2px center transparent;}
```